# Google Docs exports spreadsheet values with commas. read.csv() in R treats these as factors instead of numeric

Tags: r, csv, google-docs

I am new to R and am trying to read a public Google spreadsheet into an R data frame with numeric columns.  My problem seems to be that the exported spreadsheet has commas in large numbers, such as "13,061.422".  The read.csv() function treats this as a factor.  I tried stringsAsFactors=FALSE and colClasses=c(rep("numeric",7)) but neither worked.  Is there a way to coerce the values with commas and decimals to numeric values, either within read.csv() or afterwards when they are treated as Factors in the R dataframe?  Here is my code:

```
require(RCurl)

myCsv <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0Agbdciapt4QZdE95UDFoNHlyNnl6aGlqbGF0cDIzTlE&single=true&gid=0&range=A1%3AG4928&output=csv", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)  #ssl.verifypeer=FALSE gets around certificate issues I don't understand.

fullmatrix <- read.csv(textConnection(myCsv))

str(fullmatrix)
```

which results in:

```
'data.frame':   4927 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ wave.      : Factor w/ 4927 levels "1,000.8900","1,002.8190",..: 4875 4874 4873 4872 4871 4870 4869 4868 4867 4866 ...
 $ wavelength : Factor w/ 4927 levels "1,000.074","1,000.267",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ d2o        : num  85.2 87.7 86.3 87.6 85.6 ...
 $ di         : num  54.3 55.8 54.9 55.6 54.9 ...
 $ ddw        : num  48.2 49.7 49.4 50.2 49.6 ...
 $ ddw.old    : num  53.3 55 53.9 54.8 53.7 ...
 $ d2o.ddw.mix: num  65.8 67.9 67.2 68.4 66.8 ...
```

Thanks for any help!  I am new to R, so guessing (hoping) this is an easy one!

Comment: If you like any of the tow answers you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Two methods. The easiest to understand at first is probably just to is `as.is=TRUE` to preserve them as character vectors and then use `gsub` to remove the commas and any currency symbols before converting to numeric. The second is a bit more difficult, but I think more kewl. Create an as-method for the format you are using. Then you can use `colClasses` to do it in one step.

I see @EDi already did version #1 (using `stringsAsFactors` rather than `as.is`, so I will document strategy #2:

```
 library(methods)
 setClass("num.with.commas")
#[1] "num.with.commas"
 setAs("character", "num.with.commas",
      function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", from)))
 require(RCurl)
#Loading required package: RCurl
#Loading required package: bitops

 myCsv <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0Agbdciapt4QZdE95UDFoNHlyNnl6aGlqbGF0cDIzTlE&single=true&gid=0&range=A1%3AG4928&output=csv", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)  
> fullmatrix <- read.csv(textConnection(myCsv), 
                       colClasses=c(rep("num.with.commas",2), rep("numeric",4) ))
 str(fullmatrix)
#--------------
'data.frame':   4927 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ wave.      : num  9999 9997 9995 9993 9992 ...
 $ wavelength : num  1000 1000 1000 1001 1001 ...
 $ d2o        : num  85.2 87.7 86.3 87.6 85.6 ...
 $ di         : num  54.3 55.8 54.9 55.6 54.9 ...
 $ ddw        : num  48.2 49.7 49.4 50.2 49.6 ...
 $ ddw.old    : num  53.3 55 53.9 54.8 53.7 ...
 $ d2o.ddw.mix: num  65.8 67.9 67.2 68.4 66.8 ...
```

as-methods are coercive. There are many such methods in base R, such as `as.list`, `as.numeric`, `as.character`. In each case they attempt to take input that is in one mode and make a sensible copy of that in a different mode. For instance, it makes sense to coerce a matrix to a dataframe because they both have two dimensions. It makes a bit less sense to coerce a dataframe to a matrix (but it does succeed with loss of all the attributes of the columns and coercion to a common mode.)

In the present case I am taking a character string as input, removing any commas, and coercing the character values to numeric. Then I use `read.table`'s ( in this case by way of `read.csv`) 'colClasses' argument to dispatch to the as-method I registered with `setAs`. You may want to go to the `help(setAs)` page for more details. The S4 class system confuses a lot of people, me included. This is about the only area of success I have had with S4 methods.

Comment: Thanks!  Agree very cool.  It works for me, but don't fully understand...yet :)

Comment: I will add some more explanatory text.

Answer (score 8):

Read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in, remove the commas (with `gsub()`) and convert to numeric (with `as.numeric()`):

```
> fullmatrix <- read.csv(textConnection(myCsv), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> str(fullmatrix)
'data.frame':   4927 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ wave.      : chr  "9,999.2590" "9,997.3300" "9,995.4010" "9,993.4730" ...
 $ wavelength : chr  "1,000.07410549122" "1,000.26707130804" "1,000.46011160533" "1,000.65312629553" ...
 $ d2o        : num  85.2 87.7 86.3 87.6 85.6 ...
 $ di         : num  54.3 55.8 54.9 55.6 54.9 ...
 $ ddw        : num  48.2 49.7 49.4 50.2 49.6 ...
 $ ddw.old    : num  53.3 55 53.9 54.8 53.7 ...
 $ d2o.ddw.mix: num  65.8 67.9 67.2 68.4 66.8 ...

> fullmatrix$wave. <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", fullmatrix$wave.)) 
> fullmatrix$wavelength <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", fullmatrix$wavelength))

> str(fullmatrix)
'data.frame':   4927 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ wave.      : num  9999 9997 9995 9993 9992 ...
 $ wavelength : num  1000 1000 1000 1001 1001 ...
 $ d2o        : num  85.2 87.7 86.3 87.6 85.6 ...
 $ di         : num  54.3 55.8 54.9 55.6 54.9 ...
 $ ddw        : num  48.2 49.7 49.4 50.2 49.6 ...
 $ ddw.old    : num  53.3 55 53.9 54.8 53.7 ...
 $ d2o.ddw.mix: num  65.8 67.9 67.2 68.4 66.8 ...

> fullmatrix[1, 1]
[1] 9999.259
```