# Data retrived with google-spreadsheet adds comma in cell data

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using [Google spreadsheet service](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717012110/https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.spreadsheet.service.html) to retrieve data from Google spreadsheet.

I have column with price. I want to display price with comma
e.g. `40550` is represented as `40,550`.

On Google spreadsheet, when I check cell value, it doesn't have comma in it, it just display comma on UI.

But when I download spreadsheet with API, Cell data has comma in it.

Is it issue with Google spreadsheet API or it's how actually data is stored on Google spreadsheet?

Comment: An integer or long wouldn't be stored with a comma.  That's a formatting option when the information is being displayed like you're saying.  The difference is when you export a google spreadsheet and you have this formatting enabled it will export that way.  It's most likely going to convert from an integer to a string to support your modifications.  It wouldn't make you convert your values again when you're trying to make a 1:1 copy. [as.is=TRUE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651062/google-docs-exports-spreadsheet-values-with-commas-read-csv-in-r-treats-these)

Answer (score 0):

For now I created workaround. I also put type of value in column. 
So for integer type, I just strip comma.

But it would be nice to know if actual data stored on google is different than what is presented on spreadsheet UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '{:,}'.format(40550). This will return '40,550'

Comment: I think you got it wrong what I want to do here. I don't want to add comma in data. Comma is already added in data when I fetch from Google. I would like to know why that happens.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm sorry about that.